# PHPMailer send mail successfully but can't return to $.ajax success section

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer (gmail smtp) to send email from a static website form. The problem is, the email is sent successfully, but I can't get the right response in $.ajax 'success: function(result){}' section, everytime come into 'error: function(err){}' instead.

***Web Server:***
XAMPP (localhost)

Code is like below:

***HTML Form:***

```
<div id="contactus-form">
    <form id="contactUs" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="formbox" name="name"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="formbox" name="email"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="8"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button form="contactUs" name="send" id="send" type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

***JS:***

```
$('#contactUs').submit(function() {
    var message = $("#comments").val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "PHPMailer/gmail.php", 
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            message: message
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

***PHP:***

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Get data send by ajax
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('ssl://yoursmpt.com');
$mail->Port = ***;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "youraccount@email.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";

$mail->setFrom("from@email.com", "from name");
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('admin@yourdomail.com', 'Admin'); 
$mail->Subject = 'Message From Website';
$mail->msgHTML('<h4>Name: </h4>'.$name.'<br>'.'<h4>Email: </h4>'.$email.'<br>'.'<h4>Message: </h4>'.$message);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) { 
    $result = array('status'=>"error", 'message'=>"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);//
    echo json_encode($result);
} else {
    $result = array('status'=>"success", 'message'=>"Message sent.");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

I added `header('Content-Type: application/json');` for gmail.php as well.

When I click the "SendMessage" button, I got a cancelled request:

[request gmail.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWWYp.png)

[Cancelled request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y11EQ.png)

**And it's working fine locally if I add `return false;` at the end of submit() function.** Anyone could help me to figure out what happened in this case, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: I figured it out by simply adding `return false;` at the end of submit function.  No quite sure why. If someone can give me any advice, that will be awesome.

Comment: show your html form and any errors in browser console and response from `gmail.php`

Comment: @Rafee 
I had added errors screenshots link from gmail.php. Sorry without enough reputation I can't post a picture directly.

Comment: first image doesnt work, can you try to get the errors in gmail.php?

Comment: @Rafee Actually there is no error in gmail.php. I think the problem is I didn't prevent default submit function. Add `return false;` working is because the default submit is prevented. Add `event.preventDefault()` in `$('#contactUs').submit(function() {}` is also working.

Comment: Well, if you need json response, try the Hexxfir answer. hope that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I didn't prevent the default submit function.

Solution 1: Add `return false;` at the end of submit function

```
$('#contactUs').submit(function() {
    ...
    $.ajax({
        url: "PHPMailer/gmail.php", 
        method: "POST",
        data: {...},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Solution 2: Add event.preventDefault() in submit function

```
$('#contactUs').submit(function(e) {
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "PHPMailer/gmail.php", 
        method: "POST",
        data: {...},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

In this case, it has no difference between Solution1 and Solution2. But if you don't want to also prevent the events from propagating (any same event in parent elements), it's better to use `event.preventDefault()`. Please check https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/.

I'll appreciate if anyone can add more explanation for why without prevent default submit will cause $.ajax response error.

Answer (score 5):

try to remove this:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
```

it work for me.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I had the same issue recently and this works. Logging to a file also works fine. So, an issue with the mailer.

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
  // write to file
};

Answer (score 1):

You have key value is give "status" but i think key value is "success".

Your code :

```
$result = array('status'=>"success", 'message'=>"Message sent.");
```

Replace With this :

```
$result = array('success'=>"successfully send", 'message'=>"Message sent.");
```

**METHOD 2 :**
And above solution not work then Other Method is this. i am use this.

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => "You contact information has been sent"));
```

and get result like that :

```
    success: function (response) {
       console.log(response);
        if(response.success)
           jQuery('#success').html(response.result).show();
        else
            jQuery('#error').html(response.result).show();  
},
```

i am not sure about this but just try it. i hope is use ful

Comment: Thank you so much. If `$mail->send()` return false when calling gmail.php, it still should return to success function in JS, with response `{status: 'error', message: 'error msg'}`. But the request is been cancelled for some reason even the mail is sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

To verify, replace last part of your php, where you checking for errors by that:

```
if(!$mail->send())
    $result = "Error";
else
    $result = "Success";
```

and insert an stringify alert on both, success and error in your js. Start with one in success, after delete the one from success and try the samething in error.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result));

alert(JSON.stringify(err));
```

With that you'll see first, if the problem come when you validating. i can be wrong, but i think it comes from that part. If you receive success in error again, that come from somewhere else.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But the problem is the whole request is been cancelled for some reason. Neither "$result = 'Error'" nor "$result='Success'" has been returned.